# Can´t reach WCF in local

Tags: android, wcf, retrofit2

After Following a few tuto I programmed this code, which is not working. When I call the activity which contains Retrofit called, app crashed (that happens when I add the code for creating Retrofit object)....
I´m trying to consume a WCF (**URL**=http://192.168.0.156:52896/Service1.svc) (**method´s name**=devolverPisosA())

```
-- Interface --
public interface RestApi {
@GET("/devolverPisosA")
Call<List<pisoAlquiler>> devolverPisosA();
}

-- Pojo Class --
public class pisoAlquiler {
private int codigo;
private String fotos;
// GET AND SET INCLUDED...
}

-- Activity --
public class Alquiler extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback<List<pisoAlquiler>> {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.156:52896/Service1.svc";

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alquiler);

        // CREATE CLIENT SERVICE
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        // prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
        RestApi restApi = retrofit.create(RestApi.class);

        Call<List<pisoAlquiler>> call = restApi.devolverPisosA();
        //asynchronous call
        call.enqueue(this);
}


@Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<pisoAlquiler>> call, Response<List<pisoAlquiler>> response) {
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

    responsePisosAlquiler = (ArrayList<pisoAlquiler>) response.body();
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<List<pisoAlquiler>> call, Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(Alquiler.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

So my main_activity is calling (and starting a new activity) a second activity (which launch retrofit), but I never got to reach it. Second activity returns to main_activity instantly without doing anything (retrofit stuff)...

Thanks Mates...

EDITED:
The problem (and I´m guessing) could be my definition of endpoints. When I´m setting retrofit with baseUrl and get... My WCF looks like **http://192.168.0.156:52896/Service1.svc** and the method which I want to call is **devolverPisosA**, but I don´t know how to set retrofit for consuming it.

Just trying

baseUrl = **http://192.168.0.156:52896/Service1.svc/**
@GET("**devolverPisosA**")

Comment: did you declare the activity in the manifest ?

Comment: App crashed? Please provide the logcat

Comment: I´m using Android Studio, when I create an activity, AS is doing for me (I hope). You mean this? <activity android:name=".Alquiler" />

Comment: Sorry, It´s not crashed. It returns to main_activity. And I suppose that it happens because in Second_activity(Home, who is calling the Retrofit activity trough case), there is a Default option (R.id.menu_alquiler:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Alquiler.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;Default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);)

Comment: It's not crashing (I would edit your question since apparently it's inaccurate) and you know why it's doing what it's doing.  So what is your question?

Comment: Edited. Thanks Nasch. Retrofit is not working, so its activity is doing nothing. The problem (and I´m guessing) could be my definition of endpoints. When I´m setting retrofit with baseUrl and get... My WCF looks like http://192.168.0.156:52896/Service1.svc and the method which I want to call is devolverPisosA, but I don´t know how to set retrofit for consuming it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

The problem was I´m in Debbug Mode and WCF (by Visual Studio) and Android Studio wasn´t configurated in the same network.

For configuring Visual Studio for working with Android Studio in a Local Network, following the next:

**Web.Config** must to be set for listening from differents places. Between services and Behavior tags:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Open **applicationhost.config** allocated in Project Folder --> Config: Change the next one:

```
<site name="Proyect" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\ProjectFolder\Proyect />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52896:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

For:

```
<site name="Proyect" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\ProjectFolder\Proyect" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52896:localhost" />
              <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52896:*" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

With this, We can listen internal request.

Open Windows Firewall for that port.